# iOS In-App-Purchase Sandbox Environment Product issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I’m new for IAP feature in iOS. I sent my couple of day to test IAP for learning purpose  bur did not get success.
Something  I’m missing to implement or whatever I don’t know exactly thats why I’m asking here. [Basically I wrote code from this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) and my system is iOS 9/10 and Xcode 7/8 actually I tried with both.

I did all the step correctly Make “Test User”, Remove iTunes account from the device etc and also [test cases from this web link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/) but still facing **“In Valid Product ID”** don’t know why? but did not get list of product(s) from iTunes.

> Just clear me for below point
>
> 1) Do I need upload app on AppStore *(temporary then reject it)* for first time test IAP in sandbox environment or no need to do?
>
> 2) Do I need to add ”Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" in iTunes for sandbox environment or no need to do? *(Right now added in my iTunes Account)*

I added product on iTunes with and without screenshot uploaded but each time when I upload screenshot with product in iTunes then status was **“Ready to Submit”** and and without screenshot status was **“Missing Metadata”**

Is it correct status? and can we test IAP purchase with this status in Sandbox Environment?

Comment: Yes, you need to update Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information in sandbox mode. “Missing Metadata” is not a problem in sandbox mode.

Comment: @Poles - Thanks for your quick reply but I already added.

Comment: If you still facing "In Valid Product ID", please check the product id you mentioned in your app and also in itunes are same or not?

Comment: i checked, Both are same.

Comment: Ok. Check few more things. **1.** You did not use an explicit App ID.
**2.** You did not use the Provisioning Profile associated with your explicit App ID.
**3.** You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. See Technical Q&A, QA1329, 'In App Purchase Product Identifiers' for more information about product identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

1) No. There is no need to upload an App and reject it in order to test In-App purchases. You only need to create a sandbox account.

2)Yes, add the required information.

Make sure you have properly submitted each In-App purchase **AND** added them to the app - both steps required.